# How to test whether report has been called with "draft" option

Tags: conditionals, optional-arguments, package-options, report

How can I test within a document, whether or not the initial

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,fleqn,draft]{report}
```

includes the "draft" option? My naive attempt

```
\newif\ifmydraft
\mydraftfalse
\DeclareOption{draft}{\mydrafttrue}
```

does not work, and breaks a later `\usepackage` command.

Comment: See package ifdraft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the "ifdraft" package and use one of these:

```
\ifdraft{draftcase}{finalcase}  
\ifoptiondraft{option draft is given}{option draft is not given} 
\ifoptionfinal{option final is given}{option final is not given}
```

Comment: If I understand the short code `ifdraft.sty` correctly, what was missing in my attempt was the command `\ProcessOptions*\relax`.

Answer (score 5):

the draft option just does

```
\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
```

so you can use the test

```
\ifdim\overfullrule>0pt
    draft
\else
    not draft
\fi
```