# Disable a package/classoption when the draft mode is on

Tags: class-options, ifthenelse, draft, documentclass

I have a custom `.cls` file which passes the parameters of the `\documentclass` to `a4paper`.

In this `.cls` file, I have (from the top),

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Thesis}
              [2000/1/01 v0.1
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
```

I would like to modify here so that if `draft` is present, then removes `twoside` that `book` (I assume) option passes and replace it with `oneside`.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240128/2388. There is also the ifdraft package.

Comment: nice, this answers the second part of the question! Thank you!!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So does this mean that if I set `\overfullrule=0` before loading of some package, then draft mode isn't applied on those packages? If so, that is not a good design (in a sense that it isn't obvious for anyone).

Comment: depends on what these packages are doing. They could implement their own option code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yeah okay. But `\ifdim\overfullrule>0pt` does not work for .cls because this need to happen before \overfullrule is overwritten... whmmm

Comment: sorry but why don't you simply define your own draft option?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't know how, and that's the problem.
How do I check through \CurrentOption and see if "draft" option is past? The question essentially asks this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

All I had to do was to put this

```
\DeclareOption{draft}{\PassOptionsToClass{oneside}{\baseclass}\PassOptionsToClass{draft}{\baseclass}}
```

after

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Thesis}
              [2000/1/01 v0.1
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
```